# How to span header/footer text to all fields

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm utterly fed up with M$ Word behaviour and writing a template of the  research report based on fancy and shining Word template. I'm using `fancyhdr` package to tune the header and footer.

The problem is, that in the footer there is wide image consisting of 3 logos (let's call it paybar) followed by laboratory adress on the left side and identification number on the right side.

I've tried

```
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{paybar}}\\
Lab Name&ID 1\\
Lab Affiliation&ID 2\\
Adress&Page \thepage/\pages
\end{tabular}}
```

But the table is narrow because it leaves space for `\fancyfoot[RL]{stuff}`.

How can I either

- Merge all three fields into one, or
- tell `fancyhdr` to ignore left and right fields, or
- set width of left and right fields to `0mm`?

Comment: What do you mean by "But the table is [too] narrow to leave space for `\fancyfoot[RL]{stuff}`"? That seems contradictory. Can you show an image?

Comment: `\fancyfoot[C]` is set in a box that is independent from `\fancyfoot[R]` and `\fancyfoot[L]`. So, `\fancyfoot[C]` does not leave space for `\fancyfoot[RL]`. Do you have stuff in `\fancyfoot[RL]`? Or do you want the footer to span the entire width of the text block?

Comment: So is `paybar` just as wide as `\textwidth` when you set `height=10mm`?

Comment: @Werner Good point, let me check... Edit: Well, it did work. Going to bury myself in shame :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42677/discussion-between-crowley-and-werner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code from [`fancyhdr.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty) that sets the header:

```
\def\@fancyhead#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
  \@fancyvbox\headheight{\hbox
    {\rlap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
      \parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
      \llap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4}}}\headrule}}#5}
```

In general terms it *overlaps* the left/centre/right headers by setting the left/right header in a zero-width `par`graph `box` that is left/right aligned (using `\rlap`/`\llap`). The footer is created in an analygous way:

```
\def\@fancyfoot#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
    \@fancyvbox\footskip{\footrule
      \hbox{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
        \parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
        \llap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4}}}}}#5}
```

So technically you could represent what looks like a left/right header/footer using only the `C`entred header/footer, just as long as you make the centre element as wide as the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{ l | r }
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[height=10mm,width=\textwidth]{example-image}} \\
    Lab Name        & ID 1 \\
    Lab Affiliation & ID 2
  \end{tabular}}

\setlength{\footskip}{32pt}% ...because fancyhdr suggested at least 30.5255pt

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The second column stretches as far as needed due to the overly wide `\multicolumn` contents, thereby making the `r`ight column sit at the end of the text block.